# Help finding issue with tooltip on CMFCMenuBar

Tags: mfc, visual-c++, mfc-feature-pack

I have an MFC app using the new UI features released in the Feature Pack and I'm having trouble with tooltips on the menubar.

By default, I beleive tooltips are not enabled on menu items. Yet whenever I hover over the 2nd item in any of the menu lists I get a tooltip with "Untitled" in the popup. The only time this does not occur is when the second item is a seperator. This only occurs on the 2nd item, not on any other item in the list. What's also odd is that a tooltip popup appears when hovering over the "Edit" top level menu item.

So to illustrate, top level menu:

File Edit View Help (Hovering over "Edit" displays the tooltip)

To Illustrate the File menu

File
New
Open
Save
Save As

(Hovering over "Open" displays the tooltip)

Again the same behavior occurs for the second item on each of the menu sections. None of the other mennu items display tooltips.

Any help on how I might be able to pin down this probelm is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem. Without going into the back story, I had to merge resource ID's from another project into the Resource.h file in this project. IDR_MAINFRAME was set to a value of 2 from a very old project. MFC apparently does not like 2 for this resource ID. I change it to 128 which seems to be the default value used by the new app wizard. All is well now.